# ASP.NET MVC 3: Can I pass a modelbound object to a FilterAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, modelbinders, actionfilterattribute

I have a controller method with a custom FilterAttribute on it...

```
[ActivityHistory]
public ActionResult Index(Vehicle vehicle, string componentName)
{
    return PartialView("_Description");
}
```

The Activityhistory class...

```
public class ActivityHistoryAttribute : FilterAttribute, IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
      //I would like to use the Vehicle object passed into the controller here
      //The cotroller call is made from jQuery and json, the ASP.NET MVC modelbinding
      // is creating the c# object instance.  Can I resuse this object within this method? 
    }
 }
```

That's pretty much my question, can I reuse the modelbound Vehicle object in my custom attribute class? How do I pass a reference to that object to the custom attribute class.

Thanks for any tips or ideas on how I can accomplish this, if its even possible.

Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 4, accepted):

var vehicle = filterContext.ActionParameters["vehicle"] as Vehicle

Comment: This works but you need no implement IActionFilter instead of IResult filter. ActionParameters does not exist on ResultExecuting. Good answer though!